# Need to extract Encoded data in Jmeter, data is there in table

Tags: jmeter

Here is the sample URL

It is a Get Request,
and the previous request-response is a table form data, so I m not able to extract the pno, zip, log in.

And what I am getting in data pno=453453, zip=12345, in the previous request's response

Answer (score 1):

You could use several [Regular Expression Extractors](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) configured like:

[image]

and then refer the extracted value as `${pno}` where required

[image]

More information:

- [JMeter: Regular Expressions](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html)
- [Using RegEx (Regular Expression Extractor) with JMeter](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421325-Using-RegEx-Regular-Expression-Extractor-with-JMeter)
- [Perl 5 Regex Cheat sheet](https://perlmaven.com/regex-cheat-sheet)